# closed 1-form on Torus

Tags: geometry

How we can write explicitly a analytic closed 1-form  $\alpha$ on Torus T^n ?
Knowing that a torus is not a Banach space, then $\Omega_P(T^n)$ is not a vector space, which don't allow me to write $\alpha= \sum _{i=1}^n \alpha_i(x) dx_i $.

Comment: Your expression for $\alpha$ does make sense (assuming the $\alpha_{i}$ are suitably-periodic functions), and is the obvious way of writing a $1$-form on a torus. I don't understand the relevance of your comment about the torus not being a Banach space, however, and so don't understand why your expression for $\alpha$ doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: If $\Omega_p(T^n)$ is not a vector space, then there is no basis $(dx_i)_{i=1,n}$ hence we can't write expand $\alpha$.

Comment: The $dx_{i}$ are (formally) differentials of affine coordinates on the torus, so each is a global $1$-form. (If it matters, the space of $p$-forms on a manifold is always a vector space. You're correct, however, that the $dx_{i}$ are not a _basis_ for the real vector space of $1$-forms on the torus; they're a basis for the space of $1$-forms as a module over the algebra of smooth functions.)

Comment: Yes, you are write. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're very welcome! :)